# Protect linux kiosk display

Tags: linux

We use a small computer with linux attached to a big tv to display some data to the public.
Normally, there is no keyboard connected. When a keyboard is connected at boot, we start the configuration screens. A browser displayed in full screen after boot.

I protected the BIOS with password.

How can I avoid that someone connects in single user mode to access to files.

Is there other things that I can do to protect against hack ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rule of the thumb: If you can physically touch a device, you own it. If anyone can physically reach the box, they can pretty much do whatever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: try to restrict access**

In addition to setting a BIOS password...

Set a password for grub (this prevents changing of the stored boot command lines, but tere are still ways around this)

Require the [root password](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/password-protect-single-user-mode/) for access in single-user mode.

Restrict physical access to the box and it's ports.

**Option 2: make the controlled content unavailable at boot time**

Keep all the sensitive content in an encrypted filesystem with a manually entered passphrase. Add an unmount script for the filesystem to the runlevel scripts.

Obviously Option 2 does not provide for protection against malware installed on the system after you come along and mount the encrypted filesystem - hence you should use both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could always utilize a [USB port blocker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001XUQPAA) to physically block access to any USB ports.  You only really need one of these per device... the other USB ports can be dealt with super glue (or most likely a different non-permanent solution).

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect the system to prevent physical access, otherwise anyone with a USB keyboard can gain control of your system.

There are a couple of options you could explore if you are willing to require that someone be present every time the system need to be booted:

- Bios password/boot password: you could set a boot password to prevent unauthorized users from booting the system
- Key based encryption: you could require a USB key be inserted to boot and decrypt the system

As I said, these will prevent unauthorized use but the system can't reboot on its own, someone would have to go there.

Comment: Thoses screens are installed on site. They have physical access to them... Do you have other ideas to prevent abuses ? Thanks !

Comment: When GdD says "prevent physical access", it most likely means to keep the box enclosed in a locked cabinet, or in a separate room. The screen is an unlikely attack point; you should concentrate on protecting the computer itself.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thanks @JonathanGarber